# passing a function as a parameter to a regular class in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to pass a function to a regular class (not a widget class) in flutter and inside that class, I have a dialog box. I want to call the dialog box and when the user presses a button the function is passed as a parameter that should trigger.

This is my regular class code

```dart
import 'package:finsec/core/res/strings.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../../../core/res/text_sizes.dart';
import '../../data/repositories/app_database.dart';

class ShowDialog  {
  final void Function() onPressCallback;
  BuildContext context;
  ShowDialog (this.onPressCallback, this.context) ;
 

  Future<String> showMyDialog() async {
    return showDialog<String>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Income Data'),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListBody(
              children: const <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Do you want to apply these changes for future income transactions?',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: text_size_18,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  '\nPress NO if changes are only for this week income. Press Yes to apply changes to future weeks.',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: text_size_18,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),

          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context, successful);
              },
              child: const Text(cancelButton),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
             
                onPressCallback();
                Navigator.pop(context, successful);
              },
              child: const Text(noButton),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
              
                onPressCallback();
                Navigator.pop(context, successful);
              },
              child: const Text(yesButton),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I am calling `ShowDialog` class like this in my widget class. Below is the function call

```dart
CupertinoButton(
  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  onPressed: () async {
    await ShowDialog(
      await database.deleteIncomeData(transaction), 
      context,
    );
  },
),
```

My code is working but not as expected. When I pass my function as a parameter, the `database.deleteIncomeData(transaction)` executes immediately and my `showMyDialog()` function in `ShowDialog` class doesn't get called. When I pass a function as a parameter to `ShowDialog` class, I don't want the function to execute immediately.  I want my dialog box function to be called and show a dialog box. When the user presses a button on the dialog box, then the function parameter should execute.

Can someone help me how to modify my code to accomplish what I described above? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `return` statement is missing in `CupertinoButton` class

Comment: the CupertinoButton doesnt seem like the problem. it is list as part of a list of widgets listed using Row widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend learning more about `Future` and `async/await`.

Be careful, because your class `ShowDialog` is waiting for two parameters, one is a Function and the other is the context.

There are some errors in this line

```dart
await ShowDialog(
  await database.deleteIncomeData(transaction), 
  context,
);
```

First, you don't need to `await` because here you are calling the constructor. You have to call the `showMyDialog` method.

```dart
await ShowDialog(
  await database.deleteIncomeData(transaction),
  context,
).showMyDialog();
```

So, in that case, you will have something to `await`. The result of `showMyDialog`.

And the second one is that you are **not** passing a Function to the constructor, you are passing the value that `await database.deleteIncomeData(transaction)` returns.

(Unless the value that returns is a Function, in that case, it is ok)

And to fix that you have to pass a Function that calls `database.deleteIncomeData(transaction)`

```dart
await ShowDialog(
  () => await database.deleteIncomeData(transaction),
  context,
).showMyDialog();
```

Comment: thank you so much Leandro.  This is great. it works.  the only thing is that you probably forgot to add async before =>.   Flutter complained that I cannot call await without adding async keyword.  i changed it like this                                                                   ```              await ShowDialog( () async => await database.deleteIncomeData(transaction), context).showMyDialog();

Comment: You are right. Bonus tip. It works if you remove that async and the await next to it.